# Compiling mono-basic causes 'System.Xml.dll' could not be found

Tags: make, mono, alma-linux

I am running on AlmaLinux9 (RedHat 9 clone) and have added mono-* from the EPEL repos. All worked well, but I also needed mono-vbnc so I downloaded the mono-basic project source from github. I ran ./configure and then make, but make is having trouble finding a dll:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/mono-basic/mono-basic-main/tools'
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/mono-basic/mono-basic-main/tools/extract-source'
make all-local
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/src/mono-basic/mono-basic-main/tools/extract-source'
MONO_PATH="../../class/lib/bootstrap:$MONO_PATH" mono  --debug 
../../class/lib/bootstrap/vbnc.exe   /sdkpath:/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5-api/ -debug -r:System.Xml.dll -noconfig -define:_MYTYPE=\"Empty\" /novbruntimeref /r:../../class/lib/bootstrap/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll -target:exe -out:extract-source.exe   @extract-source.exe.sources
    Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943 (Mono 4.6 - master/c93133db)
    Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

vbnc : Command line : error VBNC2017: The library 'System.Xml.dll' could not be found.
There were 1 errors and 0 warnings.
Compilation took 00:00:00.2951750
make[3]: *** [../../build/executable.make:81: extract-source.exe] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/mono-basic/mono-basic-main/tools/extract-source'
make[2]: *** [../../build/rules.make:122: do-all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/mono-basic/mono-basic-main/tools/extract-source'
make[1]: *** [../build/rules.make:134: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/mono-basic/mono-basic-main/tools'
make: *** [build/rules.make:134: all-recursive] Error 1
```

I confirmed that System.Xml.dll is on my system:

```
$ find / -name System.Xml.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Xml.dll
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/System.Xml.dll
```

I have no idea how to fix this (new to mono). Do I need to specify a prefix for configure to point to /usr/lib/mono/4.5 ?

Comment: What is the content of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set, and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/* does not contain reference to any mono dirs.  To what dir should it point?  (And shouldn't that have been set with the mono-* packages)

Comment: I finally added a fedora 38 package called mono-basic, and that worked.  So I gave up